# Layout UIView without adding it to subview

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a Grid view that reuses Cells, supports header and footer and also supports constraints.

But I'm getting a bad time with the layout of the constraints, because I add everything to a ScrollView, the constraints doesn't want to work. I already try

`sizeThatFits`
`setNeedsUpdateConstraints`
`updateConstraintsIfNeeded`
`setNeedsLayout`
`layoutIfNeeded`

I'm doing this because I didn't find any grid View that supports everything that was developed in swift or obj-c

Any idea on how I can force that the UI calculate the Constraints before adding it to the Scroll view?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but if you found a objective c component doing evething you need, you could use it perfectly on a swift application. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) for more details

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I know but 1-. I didn't find any and 2-. I thought i will be good to do it, just to learn

Comment: Since you said "I didn't find any grid View that supports everything and is developed in swift." I thought you did find objetive c components doing everything you need. I apologize for the misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea on how I can force that the UI calculate the Constraints
>   before adding it to the Scroll view?

You can try calling -layoutIfNeeded, but it may not work. The OS is probably optimized not to layout views that are not part of the view hierarchy. Even if it works, it will get laid out again when it's added as a subview to another view.

> But I'm getting a bad time with the layout of the constraints, because
>   I add everything to a ScrollView, the constraints doesn't want to
>   work.

To get auto layout working with a scroll view, you'll want to add all of your objects to a single view, then add that one view to the scroll view.

Using scroll views with auto layout is tricky. I still cringe every time I have to do it.

Comment: Hi dave, I already try layoutIfNeeded and doesn't work. I will try putting everything into a UIView and see if it works

Comment: Things may have changed since 2015. As of this writing, I am using XCode 12.3 and targeting iOS 14. Actually calling `layoutIfNeeded` lays out the view even though the view has not been added to the view hierarchy.